# Difference between .Delete and .Clear in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, function

What is the difference between `Worksheets(1).Cells.Delete` and `Worksheets(1).Cells.Clear`?

I'm asking this because I've always used `.Clear` to clear my Worksheet content, but in my previous post I've discovered that `Worksheets(1).Cells.Delete` not only delete my Worksheet content but it also set Columns on their default width!

Can anyone explain me the difference? And also can I give a range to `.Delete` ?

Comment: `.clear` is kind of the equivalent of clicking into a cell and pressing backspace until the content is gone. This gets rid of the text and formatting, but nothing else, the cell settings are still there. `.delete` is a bit more rigorous than that, it gets rid of the entire cell altogether and replaces it with a completely new one. All formatting, settings, and content are gone, and you start with a fresh cell.

Comment: So `.Delete` basically deletes the entire cell and replace it with a new one? But there is someting strange with this function I mean... Wait let me edit the post.

Comment: @Plutian What is the difference between cell settings and formatting? Genuine question.

Comment: @QHarr formatting is all things that determine how the displayed text is shown. Think **Bold** _Italic_ or `cell colour`. Cell settings are more like <- cell with ->, conditional formatting, and the specified "number formatting". See my answer for documentation of different `.clear` varieties that clear certain types of settings and formatting depending on your situation.

Comment: @Plutian But if I right click format cells I see the list of many things which I would have thought of as _settings_ such as number formatting. Ah... I have just seen your answer _certain types of formatting_

Comment: @QHarr Perhaps the difference isn't that big, since the words are virtually synonymous, there would be several experts using either word to explain the same thing. I personally think of the difference more like: "Formatting" can be done within the cell, you can have **Bold** text next to normal text. "Settings" are things that influence the entire cell, like border and with, background colour and the like. You can't have a bit of a cell displaying it, its either all or nothing. As I said, see my or @buran answers to see `.clear` handles that tailor specifically to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Range.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.delete) actually delete respective range and shifts/move cells accordingly thus changing the structure of the worksheet. It's same if you select cells and right-click to Delete selection. You get asked how do you want to move cells.

[`Range.Clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clear) will just clear the content and formatting, but will not delete cells and not change the structure of the worksheet.

There is also [`Range.ClearContents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearcontents) that will clear just content, but preserve formatting, [`Range.ClearFormats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearformats) to just clear formatting of the cells and [`Range.ClearComments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearcomments), [`Range.ClearHyperlinks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearhyperlinks), [`Range.ClearNotes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearnotes) and [`Range.ClearOutline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearoutline)

Answer (score 5):

There is a variety of `.clear` functions available in excel vba, tailored specifically to each situation and what you are trying to accomplish. Some documentation and explanation can be found [on this page](https://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-clear-cell-contents-clearcontents/)
Here is a list of the several varieties:

```
Clear            Remove formatting and contents 
ClearFormats     Remove cell formatting, including font format 
ClearComments    Remove comments 
ClearHyperlinks  Reomve hyperlinks, but the default format of hyperlink is not removed 
Clear Notes      Remove Notes 
ClearOutline     Remove Outline 
Delete           Remove the entire cell
```

An in-depth explanation of `.delete` behaviour [can be found here.](https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/range/m/delete/)

In short, `.clear` removes cell contents and certain types of formatting when specified. `.delete` removes the entire cell and whatever formatting and shifts the rest of the documents in to cover the gap.

@ChangeWorld to answer your edited question:
`.delete` deletes the cell entirely, but shifts the cells around it to cover the gap. Like water flowing in a hole. The cell that replaces it can be below and have the same settings applied to it. If you want the settings to disappear completely use `.entirerow.delete` which gets rid of the row and replaces it with the one below it. `.entirecolumn.delete` gets rid of the column and replaces it with the one on the right. Whatever cells replace the deleted ones, the settings and formatting from those cells will then apply.