# VBA index/match formula returns an empty string despite the formula being correct

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to write a macro to create an index/match formula which gets updated dynamically while running through a range of input values, which are in columns R (company codes) and AF (calendar years). Relevant parts of the code are below. I tested the macro several times and it seems that the main issue is the index/match formula line. The formula itself works fine (when written in Excel directly or copied out of the immediate window), yet the error message I get is "object-defined or application-defined error" and the following comment appears hovering over this line of code: `ws_output.Range().Offset().Value = Empty`. When I delete this line of code, everything else works fine. How can I fix this? Thank you!

```
Sub fetching_acq_data_compustat()

Dim ws_input As Worksheet
Dim strTkr As String
Dim rngTkr As Range
Dim c As Range

Dim ws_output As Worksheet

Dim strTkrCell As String
Dim strDatedCell As String

Set ws_input = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MA_ExportFiltered_RawData")
Set ws_output = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Acquirer_ETR")

ws_input.Activate

With ws_input
    Set rngTkr = .Range("R43:R3223")
    For Each c In rngTkr
    
        strTkrCell = c.Address
        
        k = 14
        If k < 16 Then
        strDatedCell = c.Offset(0, k).Address
        
        
        ws_output.Range("A1").Offset(2, 0).Value = c.Offset(0, 14).Value
        
        ws_output.Range("A1").Offset(2, 1). Value = "=INDEX( 'US acq_CUSIP data'!$A$3:$AJ$77388" & ";" & "MATCH(1; ('US acq_CUSIP data'!$I$3:$I$77388=" & "MA_ExportFiltered_RawData!" & strTkrCell & ")*('US acq_CUSIP data'!$C$3:$C$77388=" & "MA_ExportFiltered_RawData!" & strDatedCell & ");0); 26)"
        
        ws_output.Range("A1").Offset(1, 1).Value = ws_comp.Range("A1").Offset(0, 25).Value
        
        ws_output.Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Value = c.Value
        
        k = k + 1
        
        End If
        
    Next
End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.Clear` , see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57849331/19353309 Also, try to keep the line where the error is in the code and just comment it out like so `'ws_output.Range().Offset().Value = Empty` so we can see where the issue is at.

Comment: If that is a direct copy, you have a space between `ws_output.Range("A1").Offset(2, 1).` and `Value`. Often the `.Value` is superfluous anyway. Have you considered just adding the formula to the first cell then autofilling down as well? You may find it better to build up the string separately so you can check it with Debug.Print then assign it to the offset Cell